# How to use delete query with and condition in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I need to execute following query in magento

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `column1` = '" . $value1. "' and `column2`='" . $value2. "'"
```

How can I frame this in magento basis like,

```
Mage::getModel('module/model')->setId($id)->delete();
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not test it but hope it will work for you

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('model/model')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('column1',array('eq'=> $value1))
    ->addFieldToFilter('column2',array('eq' => $value2))
;

foreach($collection as $coll)
{
    Mage::getModel('module/model')->load($coll->getId())->delete();
}
```